# htaccess redirect all domain except one subfolder including the files and other subfolders inside

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm currently using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder$
RewriteRule .* https://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Which works great at redirecting the "folder" to the "newdomain," including the files within that folder, however, the subfolders within that folder still redirect.

I've tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/subfolder/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/subfolder$
RewriteRule .* https://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

As well as:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder$
RewriteRule .* https://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

with no luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder.*/$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: This works great for the first subfolder, but any folder inside that one is still redirecting.

Comment: Do you have any other htaccess file in the sub/subfolder?